# Cannot get a box to fully right align within an AppBar

Tags: css, material-ui

I have this MUI App bar which contains an image, some text, and a box containing an Icon along with some info on the logged in user.  I am having difficulty forcing the box with user info to be right aligned.  I cannot get it to go to the right edge of the page.  I can only get it to stick to the end of the last Box.
[image]

```
<AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
    <Toolbar>
        <div id="app-bar-box" style={{ width: "100%", display: "flex" }}>
            <Box id="logo-env-txt-box" justifyContent="left" style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <a href="/home">
                    <SVGLOGO className="logo_stack" />
                    <SVGLOGOHORI className="logo" />
                </a>
                <Typography className={classes.envFlag} hidden={hidden}>
                    You are on the {process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT} environment. Click{" "}
                    <a href="">here</a> to go to production.
                </Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box id="user-info-box" justifyContent="right" style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", width: "400px", height: "64px" }}>
                <i class="dds__icon dds__icon--user" style={{ fontSize: "24px", color: "#636363", marginRight: "10px" }}></i>
                <Box style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>
                    <Typography style={{ color: "#636363", fontWeight: 400, fontSize: 14 }}>
                        John Doe Admin
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography style={{ color: "#636363", fontWeight: 400, fontSize: 14 }}>
                        Product Lead
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </div>
    </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Repost)
No need to use width for your div `user-info-box`.

You can use `justifyContent : "space-between"` for your first element and you can remove both `justifyContent : "left"` and `justifyContent : "right"` of your children elements.

```
<AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
    <Toolbar>
        <div id="app-bar-box" style={{ width: "100%", display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
            <Box id="logo-env-txt-box" style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <a href="/home">
                    <SVGLOGO className="logo_stack" />
                    <SVGLOGOHORI className="logo" />
                </a>
                <Typography className={classes.envFlag} hidden={hidden}>
                    You are on the {process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT} environment. Click{" "}
                    <a href="">here</a> to go to production.
                </Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box id="user-info-box" style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", height: "auto" }}>
                <i class="dds__icon dds__icon--user" style={{ fontSize: "24px", color: "#636363", marginRight: "10px" }}></i>
                <Box style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>
                    <Typography style={{ color: "#636363", fontWeight: 400, fontSize: 14 }}>
                        John Doe Admin
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography style={{ color: "#636363", fontWeight: 400, fontSize: 14 }}>
                        Product Lead
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </div>
    </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```